# Repeat a PHP readdir code

Tags: php, html, readdir, opendir

Maybe it's a dumb question, but I wasn't able to solve it myself.

I have the following code:

```
<?php
    $path = "galeria01";
    $dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Not found: $path");
    list_dir($dir_handle,$path);

    function list_dir($dir_handle,$path)
    {
        global $div;
        $div = 001;
        global $zindex;
        $zindex = 200;
        global $margem;
        $margem = 114;
        while ((($file = readdir($dir_handle)) !== false)) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != ".." ) {
                echo PHP_EOL . '<div id="';
                echo str_pad($div, 3, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
                echo '" style="position:absolute;left:';
                echo $margem;
                echo 'px;z-index:';
                echo $zindex;
                echo '"><img src="galeria01/';
                echo $file;
                echo '" width="675" height="450" /></div>';
                echo'<span class="clear"></span>';
                $div++;
                $zindex--;
                $margem = $margem - 675;
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($dir_handle);
?>
```

As you can see, it read all files in a folder, and generates the following code:

```
<div id="001" style="position:absolute;left:114px;z-index:200"><img src="001.jpg" width="675" height="450" /></div><span class="clear"></span>
<div id="002" style="position:absolute;left:-561px;z-index:199"><img src="002.jpg" width="675" height="450" /></div><span class="clear"></span>
<div id="003" style="position:absolute;left:-1236px;z-index:198"><img src="003.jpg" width="675" height="450" /></div><span class="clear"></span>
<div id="004" style="position:absolute;left:-1911px;z-index:197"><img src="004.jpg" width="675" height="450" /></div><span class="clear"></span></div>
```

I just need to re-run the code a few times and generate all those dinamically generated divs, in the same order again, but ALWAYS decreasing the left margin and z-index values, like this:

```
    <div id="001" style="position:absolute;left:114px;z-index:200"><img src="001.jpg" width="675" height="450" /></div><span class="clear"></span>
                     (...)
    <div id="004" style="position:absolute;left:-1911px;z-index:197"><img src="004.jpg" width="675" height="450" /></div><span class="clear"></span></div>
    <div id="001" style="position:absolute;left:-2586px;z-index:196"><img src="001.jpg" width="675" height="450" /></div><span class="clear"></span>
                     (...)
```

How do I do that?

I hope it's simple and that you can kindly help me.

Thanks.

Comment: No, it makes no sense whatsoever. "from 1 to 4 than from 1 to 4"? Huh?

Comment: (HTML id values can't start with a digit.) For such things I normally call my friend [mo-du-lus](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).

Comment: Agreed, youre question makes no sense... maybe you should isolate the problem and simplify the question

Comment: First: what @hakre said. Then if I understand you want to be able to use this function multiple times but with different margins and z-indexes? So why not add a base margin and a base z-index to the function?

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same ID. Use classes.

Comment: Thank you all for pointing out that ID's starting with numbers are not allowed. I never had any error messages regarding this, but I corrected the code anyway.
@MetodMedja yes, you did understand correctly, although there are base margin and z-indexes on the code already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To re-run the code, you can always excute the code again.

In addition to that you need to move your current global variables initialization from within the function to the global scope to allow them to be modified at the additional re-runs of your code.

Here is your modified code with some comments:

```
<?php
$path = ".";
$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Not found: $path");

// do the init of these variables outside of the function and before the first call
global $zindex;
$zindex = 200;
global $margem;
$margem = 114;

// now call your function, it will behave like your original code
list_dir($dir_handle,$path);

// now call the your function again, it will pick up with the zindex/margem values of the last div you printed
list_dir($dir_handle,$path);

function list_dir($dir_handle,$path)
{
    global $div;
    $div = 001;
    global $zindex;
    // no longer set a new value for the zindex with each function call
    //$zindex = 200;
    global $margem;
    // no longer set a new value for the margem with each function call
    //$margem = 114;
    //reset the directory handle to the first position
    rewinddir($dir_handle);
    while ((($file = readdir($dir_handle)) !== false)) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != ".." ) {
            echo PHP_EOL . '<div id="';
            echo str_pad($div, 3, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
            echo '" style="position:absolute;left:';
            echo $margem;
            echo 'px;z-index:';
            echo $zindex;
            echo '"><img src="galeria01/';
            echo $file;
            echo '" width="675" height="450" /></div>';
            echo'<span class="clear"></span>';
            $div++;
            $zindex--;
            $margem = $margem - 675;
        }
    }
}
closedir($dir_handle);
?>
```

Comment: I was able to understand your thought, did exactly what you've said, but sadly the output keeps listing the files only once, as it was before.
It doesn't matter how many times I call the function, it lists only once on HTML.

Comment: that is because the dir_handle points to the end after the first function call ended. I have modified my answer to use rewinddir() before the directory content is read … therefor always reading the complete directory tree from the beginning